# Post_parent function in wordpress does not return page childs

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php
    $currentID = get_the_ID();
    $argscases = new WP_Query( array( 'post_parent' => 2431 ) );

    $my_query = new WP_Query( array('post_type' => 'page', 'showposts' => '7', 'post__in' => array_diff($argscases, array($currentID)))); 
?>
<?php
    while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post(); 
?>  
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title() ?>" class="btn btn-default btn-normal btn-inline " target="_self"><?php the_title() ?></a>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I am trying to display buttons for each page that is a child of the page with id 2431. And also exclude the button of the current page that I am viewing. But when I execute the code above I get all the pages in return. If anything is unclear I please tell me so I can clarify it.

Comment: Have you checked whether what you are trying to pass to the second query for `post__in` is actually a value that makes sense …?

Comment: You know that post__in has 2 underscores? It can be simply a typo

Comment: I checked the post__in and it's with 2 underscores.@ScorpionCode

Comment: @CBroe Tho code works when I use an array with values for $argscases but I need to get the values dynamically..

Comment: Not what I asked. Have you _checked_ whether your code actually produces such an array? Use var_dump to verify what you actually got there. // I don’t think that stuffing a WP_Query object into array_diff makes much sense. You should _create_ an actual array of the post ids that query returned first.

Comment: Ok. Thank you! I will check it and come back to you!